# min max scaling for datum

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am building a prediction model in which I have a temperature feature  that I am scaling using min-max.
All is good, however during prediction when calling my model, I have only one row for which I need to predict and therefore only one value for temperature feature which make it impossible to scale for minmax

How can I scale using minmax my temperature input feature on prediction time when I have only a datum 
.

If this is not possible, what scaling/normalization method can I use to scale my temperature feature between [0,1] that would work on a vector of n elements or 1 element only

Comment: Don't scale it at all? If there is no range, you cannot scale. It is like trying to take the standard deviation of one point. Does not make sense.

Comment: said like this, is there is one single value .. no need to scale by definition. I am also curious about this single vlaue feature ... does not seem to be a solid approach to make a predicition based on only one value.

Comment: the temperature is one among other features in my model, but is the only one that I normalize.

Comment: but you onyl have one value for this input: either it's the same for all your dataset on which you train, either your dataset contains only one element (I cannot believe this), either the population of your dataset only contains no temperature expect one. In any case, taking into account temperature is not relevant.